# jQuery Mobile Wordpress + jQuery UI google maps

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3, themes, jquery-mobile

Hello, this is baking my noodle, any help would be awesome! Thanks

The low down.. I'm building a jQuery-mobile alpha 4 site using wordpress as a CMS. I'm trying to get googles jquery maps UI to work in my theme. Simple you would think but I'm getting an error on line 318 of the jquery-maps-ui script.

I'm using a theme developed by a french dude. It's the best one I could find in my personal opinion to build on. URL > frobert.com/en/2011/03/30/generic-jquery-mobile-wordpress-theme/

My plan is to get a bit of geo locate functionality on my map page with fusion tables etc. But I cant even get the basic of basic demos to work!?? This is where I'm getting my source, all jquery mobile frameworked.. http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html

If anyone can get the basic map demo to work in this wordpress theme, could you please help :-)

If you want to re-create my exact error on your wordpress. Download the theme on the link below all ready to go with the google map-ui page scripts included. http://wtrns.fr/_PTQG94oxWzvUA

All you need to do is add a page with a slug called 'maps'

Also in the folder is a working html example of google map-ui and script. It works locally too.

Once you drop the theme in your themes folder, you need to add the wp_tap plugin also (included in the download). This is because it redirects desktop browsers to your default theme. And then the wp_tap plugin redirects devices to the jquery-mobile theme. Easy setup. With out this pluging installed, it locks you out of your admin for some reason. But if your already logged in, then it works with-out the plugin, and you can just set it to you default theme. Sounds dodgy I know but it works sweet. Give it a go if you think you can get it to work. I've included the wp-tap plugin in my download link.

Any suggestions would be so great! Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You load jquery 2 times, thats why you get that error... If you have questions about the jquery maps plugin, pls ask in the forum, [jquery google maps plugin forum](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-map-discuss). 
Change this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("maps", "3", {'other_params':'sensor=true'});
            //REMOVE THIS --> google.load("jquery", "1.5");
    </script>
```

Comment: You dont need to use the google loader, it's only used to get the client location, if it's found, via Google Maps API. You could just use the Google maps API CDN if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you so much - that is exactly why it was getting that error.

I should of known really, but I've never really seen jquery loaded like this before so did not spot it.

Again, thanks!